# App is not rendering even when the state in the redux is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having two buttons in a component thats under App component. Even though it is dispatching actions and store is updated, App is not re-rendered. Ideally on button press, I add some dummy name that will be put inside array and then a different component is rendered based on number items inside this array.

Can someone tell what is going wrong, I am a beginner to react and redux

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/panel-item-with-redux-hxmihq?file=/src/PanelAdder.js

App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Panel } from "./Panel";
import PanelAdder from "./PanelAdder";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function App() {
  const panels = useSelector((state) => state.panelItems);

  return (
    <>
      <PanelAdder />
      <div className="cards-container">
        {panels || [].map((name) => <Panel {...{ name }} />)}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

PanelAdder.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addPanel } from "./actions/counterActions";

export default function PanelAdder() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleClick = (name) => {
    dispatch(addPanel(name));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick("Panel 1")}> Add Panel 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick("Panel 2")}> Add Panel 2</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Panel.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faSquareMinus,
  faWindowMaximize,
  faRectangleXmark
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

export const Panel = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-actions">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSquareMinus} />
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faWindowMaximize} />
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faRectangleXmark} />
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">{name}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

First in your combineReducers function you are adding the reducer called panels. Redux will add this to the state object. So when you are referencing it you need to refrence the panels object that is nested inside your state object. You need to get the following in your useSelector `useSelector((state) => state.panel.panelItems)`

Second you are doing the following in your app component `{panels || [].map((name) => <Panel {...{ name }} />)}`. So what you are doing here is displaying the panels array or mapping through an empty array but you never actually map through the panels array. But what you need to do is map through the panels array. So you can just map the panels array `{panels.map((name) => <Panel {...{ name }} />)}`

So your app component should look like the following:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Panel } from "./Panel";
import PanelAdder from "./PanelAdder";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function App() {
  const panels = useSelector((state) => state.panel.panelItems);

  return (
    <>
      <PanelAdder />
      <div className="cards-container">
        {panels.map((name) => <Panel {...{ name }} />)}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: `|| []` is a very commonly used trick to have a fallback in case the operand is null or undefined, which would throw a reference error, but the whole thing has to be wrapped in parenthesis to work properly. So you're correctly pointing out why it doesn't work but I would suggest fixing it by writing it properly as `(panels || []).map ...` instead of simply removing it.

Comment: @Lennholm I understand why its there the OP was just doing it wrong and since they are using redux and passing in an initial state then there should be an empty array there anyway. It would make more sense in this type of situation to just check for the array or even the array length or just do nothing like `{panels && panels.map(...)}` instead of running the map function on an empty array.